# Raspberri pi 2 desktop toolbar flickering over xrdp

Tags: raspbian, remote

When I log into my raspberry pi 2 over remote desktop with xrdp, the desktop toolbar constantly flickers and it doesn't get fixed by re-logging, or rebooting.

Here are some images for reference; It flickers between the two states and never acts normally

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The first installation was managed with a local keyboard and screen and all the rest with Windows Remote Desktop. It works fine till I added the new users.

My "solution" was to login local once with all user names with a local screen and keyboard. After this local login also the remote console was ok.

I didn't see any change in the user directories or something else. I hope it work also with your Raspi.

Kaus